# Rust not printing to terminal

Tags: rust

rustc is not outputting anything to terminal when using `println!`.

Code:

```
fn main() {
   println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

Running it:

```
me@mclaptop:~
> rustc helloworld.rs

me@mclaptop:~
>
```

Why does it not print anything?

Comment: `rustc --verbose helloworld.rs` - still nothing =( What a puzzling language

Comment: rustc will just create a binary. if you want to run your programm there should be a helloworld binary now.

Most people don't directly use rustc. I would recommend using cargo.

Comment: puzzling language? In what other compiled language does the compiler automatically run the code? This is pretty standard behavior for a compiler actually.

Comment:  been using Ruby and Js for too long... forgot about compiled languages!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`rustc` is the compiler of the Rust language, it just produces an executable to be run. If you want to actually see the output you must run the `./helloworld` command.

You can read about it [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc/what-is-rustc.html).

Answer (score 3):

`rustc` only compiles your code. You need to call the output binary to get it working.

Try `./helloworld` or whatever the name of the output file is.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux and Mac:

```
rustrc helloworld.rs && ./helloworld
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use:

```
cargo run
```

This will compile current project and run it just with one command.